# Java 8 : Invoke Interface's static method using reflection

Tags: reflection, java-8

I want to invoke static method of Java 8 interface using reflection API.

```
public interface TimeClient {
    static void testStatic() {
        System.out.println("In the Static");
    }
}
```

I am able to invoke default method of Interface but unable to invoke static method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see no problems:

```
TimeClient.class.getDeclaredMethod("testStatic").invoke(null);
```

Works without problems and prints "In the Static". The `getMethod` also works as expected:

```
TimeClient.class.getMethod("testStatic").invoke(null);
```